# Simple jQuery for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to add a function to WordPress to strip spaces from HTML with a certain class. So that

`<div class="strip_space">Test the space</div>`

becomes Testthespace

I'm trying this script

```
jQuery(".strip_space").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(' ', '');
});
```

But all the code samples I've seen include some form of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

How would I put that together?

Cheers, Richard

Here's the snippet I'm using to register/enqueue the script

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'strip-space', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/strip-space.js',
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".strip_space").html(function () {
                return jQuery(this).html().replace(/\s/g, '');
            });
        });
```

Comment: That works! But how would I call this with a shortcode? i.e. I need to strip spaces from the result of this shortcode: `<a href='[wpbb site:user_meta key='contrib-name']'>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all whitespace, and not just the literal space character, use `\s`:

```
$('.targetElementClass').replace(/\s/g,'');
```